# Checking server status?

Tags: firebase, nest-api

Is there a way to check the status of the Nest servers?

They appear to be down right now. Currently I'm checking by firing a GET request to:

```
https://developer-api.nest.com/?auth=...
```

Which works fine, I can just set a timeout and check the status codes.

I'm using the Firebase API (OS X) and I'm wondering, maybe there is a better way I can check? I don't see anything in their API. `observeEventType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:` never gets called.

Also, will the firebase `observeEventType:` block automatically start being called once the servers are back?

Comment: I created a new account and I can login fine. Perhaps Nest have blocked my main account? Very difficult to get in contact with them...

Comment: Are you using the Firebase SDK version specified on their site? There's not enough info here to repro/understand the issue.

Comment: @Katoyes I am. The app had worked fine with my account, and works fine with another I created. I also can no longer login to other 3rd party apps. It looks like Nest has blocked my account, or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days the block appears to be lifted. I tried contacting Nest 2 days ago and I never got a reply. Perhaps they lifted the block and didn't reply, or it happened automatically.

I believe I was blocked because I was using my real account, with a real device. And obviously because I was in development I was logging in/out and changing values a lot.

I didn't realise until after the block you can create virtual devices (on a new account). More information here: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/chrome-extension

Moral of the story: use virtual devices!